# An Android app for blocking any sms containing a word or tag

Tags: android

do you know any kind of free application for Android which can block SMS messages containing specific words or tags. In other words and if I want to say it more precisely, if an SMS, contains any of the words/tags defined by me, will be blocked...

Comment: Have you tried searching on Google Play for that app you request?

Comment: Yes, mostly irrelevant, buggy, full of add, useless apps...